# Principal Class Object Null

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, authentication

I'm using principal class to implement authentication in spring boot and everytime i send the credentials to login, the Principal object sets as null.

```
 @RequestMapping("/user")
 public Principal loginAuthentication(Principal user) {

   LOGGER.debug("Request received from frontend to authenticate the user");

   try {
            LOGGER.debug("In try block to authenticate the user");
            LOGGER.debug("Returning the user object to the front end");
            return user;
   }
   catch(Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("An exception occured while trying to authenticate the user: " +e);
            LOGGER.error("Returning NULL to front end");
            return null;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of class is usually located on the authorization server.

Then from the secured resource server that you want to check if a user is authenticated, in the application.properties or application.yml you put:

```
oauth2:
    resource:
      userInfoUri: ${your_auth_server}/user
```

and spring checks it automatically, but it's not useful for login.